# Has anyone built the ADT 11 Eclipse Tools?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

Is there an easy way to built the ADT 11 tools from GIT or has anyone already built them and have a zip for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, check out the [ADT site](http://tools.android.com/download) - you can download the release candidate zip file. Should be quite easy now :)

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on your definition of easy.  Here is a writeup from one of the Google tools engineers on how to build the tools:

http://tornorbye.blogspot.com/2010/11/building-android-ide-tools.html